# PhysX SDK with Custom Game Engine

Tags: game-physics, physx, omniverse

Is anyone out there familiar with the NVidia PhysX SDK (C++)? I'm currently trying to tie it into my custom C++ game engine, but I'm finding a dramatic lack of material on the internet. It seems that either no one is using PhysX, or no one is bothering with custom game engines anymore. My game engine has been in development for over 10 years, and has burned through multiple physics APIs, including Bullet (unstable), Tokamak (unstable), and Havok (PC license disappeared over night and they ignore my emails).

Anyway, I have a couple questions, if anyone out there has any experience with this SDK.

1. Is the PhysX 5.0 SDK available? The NVidia website claims its part of Omniverse, but I've downloaded & installed Omniverse, and there is no mention of the PhysX SDK.
2. Does anyone know of a PhysX developer forum, apart from the "issues" section on PhysX GitHub? Or any good tutorials or etc? I'm using the documents and samples as a guide, but its a slow process.
3. I'm currently trying to get a grasp on collision filtering (shaders). I've noticed that some of the filter shaders within the samples use external variables like lookup tables that exist outside of the function call. If one were to use GPU based physics, would that not restrict filter shaders to only be capable of accessing local variables in these functions? Since `physx::PxFilterData` provides only 16 bytes to work with, I'm trying to figure out how to cram all of my engine's collision properties into that tiny space. Does GPU based physics even use the same type of shader? And is there an example of this in the SDK?
4. I don't see any ragdoll examples in the SDK. Just a few joint snippets. I'm assuming PhysX is capable of simulating decent ragdolls, but apart from some low quality YouTube videos, I haven't seen anything yet. My game is heavily character based, so this would be a deal breaker.